# Extracting links with title and url with selected links using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract only 10 links from this site https://dmoz-odp.org/Sports/Events/ this links can be found in the bottom of the page some of them are AOL, Google, etc

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class cr(scrapy.Spider):

 name = 'prcr'

    start_urls = ['https://dmoz-odp.org/Sports/Events/']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = '.alt-sites'
        for i in response.css(items):
            title=response.css('a::attr(title)').extract()
            link=response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
            yield dict(title=title, titletext=link)
```

this works fine but I need only the last 10 links to be extracted so please tell how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made few changes to your parse method (check the below code) and this should work just fine,

```
    def parse(self, response):

    items = '.alt-sites a'

    for i in response.css(items):
        title = i.css('::text').extract_first()
        link = i.css('::attr(href)').extract_first()
        yield dict(title=title, title_link=link)
```

hope this helps you.